# How to rescue the Linux system from erroneous insmod in rc.local in Fedora Core?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I have placed a faulty kernel object in the rc.local. Because of this faulty kernel object,the system crashes on bootup. Now, my aim is to remove that faulty ko insmod from rc.user. However, I cannot access rc.user as my system crashes on bootup. How can  I fix this issue?

Comment: The simplest solution is while booting kernel pass init=/bin/bash ( or any shell) as an kernel argument by editing your grub. you get command prompt and  do your changes and do a reboot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting the grub screen then you can
go to `runlevel 1` and change the file.

On grub screen you will have to

```
press a after selecting the Fedora kernel with which you want to boot.
APPEND single after space in that line and press enter
press b to boot in single user mode
```

You can edit any file in this mode.

Comment: How to go to runlevel 1?

Comment: @SHREYASJOSHI That is what I explained above :) [For more help](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/13/html/Installation_Guide/ap-rescuemode.html)

Answer (score 0):

The safest & easiest approach when I get into such troubles is to `mount` the HD (contaning the faulty kernel) as an external hard drive to another linux machine and manually edit the files causing trouble.

1. Do a `fdisk -l` with your HD plugged in (thorugh USB). Take notice of the <`/dev/sd*#`>.
2. `mount /media /dev/<sd*#>`

Now, you can access your `boot` or `root` partition to access the files.